# Is there any good way with FluentUI to have sticky column headers on Detail List?

Tags: fluent, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

My goal is to display my details list with Sticky Headers on scroll, and I've run into issues with every solution I've found.

The recommended solution of a ScrollablePane wrapping the list, and onRenderDetailsHeader with Sticky components (https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/1146) places the list on an absolute position on the UI.

The recommended solution of styling on FluentUI's site (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/scrollablepane) requires a specified height to be provided.

Both of these solutions require set positioning for the list whether in height or margin in order to work as expected. But, I also need to account for error message bars that may appear above the table and ensure they are not covered, or a double scroll bar appears. Anyone have a seamless example they've used?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this with FluentUI. The recommended solution of a ScrollablePane wrapping the list, and onRenderDetailsHeader with Sticky components (https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/1146) places the list on an absolute position on the UI. The recommended solution of styling on FluentUI's site (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/scrollablepane) requires a specified height to be provided. Both of these solutions require set positioning for the list whether in height or margin in order to work as expected. But, I also need to account for error message bars that may appear above the table and ensure they are not covered, or a double scroll bar appears. Anyone have a seamless example they've used?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

For sticky first column (horizontal):

```
.ms-DetailsHeader-cell:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ms-DetailsRow-cell:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

For sticky column header (vertical):

```
const scrollClass = mergeStyleSets({
    detailsListWrapper: {
        height: '320px',
        width: '100%',
        position: 'relative'
    },
});



<Stack horizontal className={scrollClass.detailsListWrapper}>
    <Stack.Item>
        <ScrollablePane scrollbarVisibility={ScrollbarVisibility.auto} >
            <Shimmer customElementsGroup={getShimmerData(4)} width="300" height="400" isDataLoaded={!dataLoading}>
                <DetailsList
                    items={entities}
                    compact={isCompactMode}
                    columns={columns}
                    selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}
                    getKey={this._getKey}
                    setKey="single"
                    layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
                    constrainMode={ConstrainMode.unconstrained}
                    isHeaderVisible={true}
                    selection={this._selection}
                    selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
                    onItemInvoked={this._onItemInvoked}
                    enterModalSelectionOnTouch={true}
                    ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
                    ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
                    checkButtonAriaLabel="select row"
                    onRenderDetailsHeader={this._renderFixedDetailsHeader}
                    styles={{ contentWrapper: { cursor: "pointer", width: '100%' } }}
                />
            </Shimmer>
        </ScrollablePane>
    </Stack.Item>
</Stack >



private _renderFixedDetailsHeader: IRenderFunction<IDetailsHeaderProps> = (props, defaultRender) => {
    if (!props) {
        return null;
    }
    const onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip: IRenderFunction<IDetailsColumnRenderTooltipProps> =
        tooltipHostProps => (
            <TooltipHost {...tooltipHostProps} />
        );
    return (
        <Sticky stickyPosition={StickyPositionType.Header} isScrollSynced>
            {defaultRender!({
                ...props,
                onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip,
            })}
        </Sticky>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ms-DetailsList-contentWrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image]